# just dash, activate just dash

Tags: unity, 2d

Is it possible to activate only dash without whole launcher?
Generally, am need command to launch unity 2d dash and make launcher.
Is this possible?
And is it possible to install unity 2d in 12.10?

Comment: Installing Unity 2d is no longer possible in 12.10 AFAIK, but the general question is interesting. I don't have 12.10, but maybe you could still install gnome-do? This is the tool I still use with 10.04, it does everything I want from a launcher and nothing more.

Comment: am using gnome-do on 11.10 in some custom session, but the reason why am need just dash is this: am have custom session openbox/gnome + cairo dock + unity 2dpanel + compiz. in cairo-dock am want to inplement launcher who open just dash and use this type of meny. we are all familiar, unity launcher most people hate, but like panel. this is something for them. instend cairo-dock, you can run docky or any other.

Comment: am not using 12.10  but sime people on ubuntu-rs official forum say that unity 2d is possible to install from software center after instalacion of 12.10, just like gnome-shell, xfce and other